# Google Drive : gsheets download through REST API

Tags: java, rest, google-api, google-drive-api

I am trying to download spreadhseets from a users google drive. I am encountering a CORS issue.

http://javascript.wekeepcoding.com/article/15417055/CORS+on+exportLinks+for+Google+Docs+spreadsheets+not+working

Reading this:

https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client/issues/47

I am trying to make a GET request on the server side. I tried using restTemplate.exchange but I am not sure what format my response should be in. Basically completely lost.

Is there a way to make the GET to pull the file and pass back to my front end?

I keep getting this error for whatever format I try:

org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [interface java.sql.Blob] and content type [application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet]

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As far as CORS goes, this is the relevant guide I can find, [How to use CORS to access Google APIs](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/features/cors)

> Use [XMLHttpRequest2](https://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/) to make
>   CORS requests.
>
> A CORS request to a Google API is similar to a REST request. The URL
>   for a CORS request follows this pattern:

```
https://www.googleapis.com +
  REST path + URL Params
Example: here is a REST request:

var restRequest = gapi.client.request({
  'path': 'https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people/me/connections',
  'params': {'sortOrder': 'LAST_NAME_ASCENDING'}
});
And here is the equivalent CORS request:

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people/me/connections?sortOrder=LAST_NAME_ASCENDING');
```

> Request headers are added to the request using
>   XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader.
>
> The request body is sent using the XMLHttpRequest.send method.
>
> You can register callbacks by adding event listeners on the load and
>   error events. Follow this link for information about XMLHttpRequest
>   events
>
> Also make sure you have permission to download the spreadsheet file
>   from the other user.